# Selecting links in NSTextField or NSTextView using keyboard Tabs, like NSButton

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nsattributedstring

I have a window in my macOS app which consists of buttons and text with hyperlinks. I created hyperlinks in NSTextView using NSAttributedString.

The question is: Can I allow a user to move focus between buttons and links in the text so that they could Enter/Space that links without using a mouse. Basically, the question is how can I achieve moving firstResponder from a button to a link in the NSTextView's text?

This picture is an example of what I exactly need as a result:
[image: Pic from apple docs]

Answer (score 1):

NSTextView does not support focus on regions of text in that manner. If you were to implement some kind of focus in a custom text view, you'd have to handle the focus nativation methods (eg, pressing the tab key), manually parse the text view to find regions you want to focus on, cycle to the next one, and draw some kind of highlighting, whether by using custom drawing, using temporary attributes on the text itself, or perhaps even just moving the selection range. Either way, you will have to do all of that input handling and "focus" movement yourself.

As for merely having clickable links in a text view, the range of text for the link needs to have the NSLinkAttributeName  attribute, with the NSURL as the value. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1487/_index.html
http://travisjeffery.com/b/2013/11/url-linking-in-a-non-editable-nstextview/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, I could do custom highlighting by updating string attributes on Tab navigation or something, but I wanted to make sure that I'm not missing any native solution...